# data is not going to mongoldb atlas in authentication system

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

Hello everyone's was making Jon seeking website, started working with NodeJS(i'm new at it, just started learning backend),I watched over 10 guides, every time I have the same problem, when I put data in register form, user is not in db, but by tutorials it must work.I don't know where is problem because link I user if correct 100%,in terminal everything is okey, writes mg is connected etc.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require( "express" )
const mongoose = require( "mongoose" )
const cors = require('cors')
const collection = require('./models/user')

const app = express()
const port = 5174

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    const [email,password] = req.body

    const data = {
        email:email,
        password:password
    }

    try {
        const check =  await collection.findOne({email,password})

        if(check){
            res.json('exist')
        } else {
            res.json('no exist')
            await collection.insertMany([data])
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.json('not exist')
    }
})

app.post('/login',async (req,res)=>{
    const [email,password] = req.body

    try {
        const check =  await collection.findOne({email,password})

        if(check){
            res.json('exist')
        } else {
            res.json('not exist')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.json('not exist')
    }
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server is running')
})
```

```
`const mongoose = require( "mongoose" )

const url = "mongodb+srv://admin:<my password>@cluster0.fecptpd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(url).then(()=>{
    console.log('mongodb connected')
}).catch(()=>{
    console.log('failed')
})

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://admin::<my password>@cluster0.fecptpd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});
async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);


const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
});

const collection = mongoose.model('collection',newSchema)

module.exports = collection`
```

here is register from frontend

```
`import React,{useState} from "react";
import {NavLink,useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

export default function Register(){

  const history = useNavigate()

  const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('')

  async function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5174/register',{
        email,password
      })
      .then(res=>{
        if (res.data == 'exist'){
          window.alert('user already exists')
        } else if (res.data == 'not exist'){
          history('/login',{state:{id:email}})
        }
      })
      .catch(e=>{
        window.alert('wrong details')
        console.log(e)
      })

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="Auth-form-container">
      <form className="Auth-form">
        <div className="Auth-form-content">
          <h3 className="Auth-form-title">Sign Up</h3>
          <div className="text-center" style={{marginBottom:'1vw',fontSize:'1.3vw',}}>
            Already registered?{" "}
            <NavLink to={'/login'} className="link-primary"  style={{cursor:'pointer',}}>
              Sign In
            </NavLink>
          </div>
          <form >
            <div className="form-group mt-3" style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center',marginBottom:'.7vw',}}>
                <label style={{width:'6.6vw',}}>Full Name</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control mt-1"
                placeholder="e.g Jane Doe"
                style={{width:'80%',fontSize:'1vw',padding:'.7vw 1vw .7vw 1vw',}}
                name='username'
                
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group mt-3"style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center',marginBottom:'.7vw',}}>
                <label style={{width:'6.6vw',}}>Email address</label>
                <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control mt-1"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                style={{width:'80%',fontSize:'1vw',padding:'.7vw 1vw .7vw 1vw',}}
                name='email'
               
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group mt-3" style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center',marginBottom:'.7vw',}}>
                <label style={{width:'6.6vw',}}>Password</label>
                <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control mt-1"
                placeholder="Password"
                style={{width:'80%',fontSize:'1vw',padding:'.7vw 1vw .7vw 1vw',}}
                name='password'
                
                />
            </div>
        </form>
        
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3" style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',}}>
            <button type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary" style={{padding:'.7vw 1vw .7vw 1vw',background:'none',width:'30%',fontSize:'.9vw',border:'solid thin lightgrey',boxShadow:' rgb(0 0 0 / 16%) 1px 1px 10px',cursor:'pointer',}}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    )
}`
```

I tried over 10 guides, same problem, expect to be able to register properly

Answer (score 0):

When you send the data in the frontend you are sending it as an object, to then use that data maybe you can try destructuring `req.body` into an object `const {email,password} = req.body` where you are using as an array

Comment: don't get it, can you please try explain it to me again

Comment: I can try, In your axios request you send the data to the backend as `{  email, password }`  , the backend then tries and extract those variables from the `req.body` as ` const [email,password] = req.body` but the request is an object (represented as curly brackets) not an array (square brackets)

Comment: noup,it haven't worked